# Multiplying the output of two layers in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to implement in keras a neural(ish) net with this design:  http://nlp.cs.rpi.edu/paper/AAAI15.pdf

The algorithm has, essentially, three inputs.  Input 2 and Input 3 get multiplied by the same weight matrix W1 to produce O2 and O3.  Input 1 gets multiplied by W2 to produce O1.  Then, we need to take the dot product of O1 * O2,  and O1 * O3.

I'm trying to implement this in keras.

My first thought was to use the keras `Graph` class and make W1 a shared node layer with two inputs and two outputs.  Fine so far.

The problem then arises of how to take the dot products of those two outputs with O1.

I tried to define a custom function:

```
   def layer_mult(X, Y):
       return K.dot(X * K.transpose(Y))
```

Then:

```
ntm.add_node(Lambda(layer_mult, output_shape = (1,1)), name = "ls_pos", inputs = ["O1", "O2"])
ntm.add_node(Lambda(layer_mult, output_shape = (1,1)), name = "ls_neg", inputs = ["O1", "O3"])
```

The problem that arises on compile, is that keras only wants to give the Lambda layer one input:

```
   1045         func = types.FunctionType(func, globals())
   1046         if hasattr(self, 'previous'):
-> 1047             return func(self.previous.get_output(train))
   1048         else:
   1049             return func(self.input)

TypeError: layer_mult() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I thought an alternative might be to use a `Merge` class, which has `dot` as a type of permitted merge.  But, the input layers for a `Merge` class have to be passed to the constructor. So, there doesn't seem to be a way of getting the outputs from the shared node into the `Merge` to add the `Merge` to the `Graph`.

If I was using `Sequential` containers, I could feed those into the `Merge`.  But, then there wouldn't be a way to implement that the two `Sequential` layers need to share the same weight matrix.

I thought about trying to concatenate O1, O2, and O3 together into a single vector as an output layer and then do the multiplication inside an objective function.  But, that would require the objective function to split its input, which doesn't seem to be possible in keras (the relevant Theano functions aren't passed-through to to keras API).

Any know a solution?

EDIT:

I thought I'd made some progress because I found that `shared_node` is implementing `dot` (even if its not in the documentation).

So I got to:

```
ntm = Graph()
ntm.add_input(name='g', input_shape=(300,))  #  Vector of 300 units, normally distributed around zero
ntm.add_node([pretrained bit], name = "lt", input = "g") # 300 * 128, output = (,128)
n_docs = 1000
ntm.add_input("d_pos", input_shape = (n_docs,)) # (,n_docs)
ntm.add_input("d_neg", input_shape = (n_docs,)) # (,n_docs)

ntm.add_shared_node(Dense(128, activation = "softmax", 
#                      weights = pretrained_W1, 
                      W_constraint = unitnorm(), 
                      W_regularizer = l2(0.001)
                      ), name = "ld", 
                    inputs = ["d_pos", "d_neg"],  
                    outputs = ["ld_pos", "ld_neg"], 
                    merge_mode=None) # n_docs * 128, output = (,128) * 2
ntm.add_shared_node(ActivityRegularization(0,0),   #ActivityRegularization is being used as a passthrough - the function of the node is to dot* its inputs
                    name = "ls_pos", 
                    inputs = ["lt", "d_pos"], 
                    merge_mode = 'dot')  # output = (,1)
ntm.add_shared_node(ActivityRegularization(0,0), 
                    name = "ls_neg", 
                    inputs = ["lt", "d_neg"], 
                    merge_mode = 'dot')  # output = (,1)
ntm.add_shared_node(ActivityRegularization(0,0), 
                    name = "summed", 
                    inputs = ["ls_pos", "ls_neg"], 
                    merge_mode = 'sum') # output = (,1)
ntm.add_node(ThresholdedReLU(0.5), 
             input = "summed", name = "loss") # output = (,1)
ntm.add_output(name = "loss_out", 
               input= "loss")
def obj(X, Y):
    return K.sum(Y)
ntm.compile(loss = {'loss_out' : obj},  optimizer = "sgd")
```

And now the error is:

```
>>> ntm.compile(loss = {'loss_out' : obj},  optimizer = "sgd")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/models.py", line 602, in compile
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py", line 149, in get_output
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 117, in get_input
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 1334, in get_output
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 1282, in get_output_sum
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 1266, in get_output_at
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 730, in get_output
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 117, in get_input
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 1340, in get_output
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 1312, in get_output_dot
  File "/Volumes/home500/anaconda/envs/[-]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/var.py", line 360, in dimshuffle
    pattern)
  File "/Volumes/home500/anaconda/envs/[-]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/elemwise.py", line 164, in __init__
    (input_broadcastable, new_order))
ValueError: ('You cannot drop a non-broadcastable dimension.', ((False, False, False, False), (0, 'x')))
```

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd suggest creating a github issue for this (though I'm no Keras developer). Moreover, what about (ab)using the Siamese layer for this, producing O1 twice with a shared weight matrix?

Comment: Hi, did you figure out the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

main_branch.add(Merge([branch_1, branch_2], mode = 'dot'))

Comment: I'm accepting the answer so folks don't need to keep commenting on this.  It turned out to be very easy, and your response is an example of one way to do it.

Comment: I am trying something similar [please take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297359/typeerror-output-tensors-to-a-model-must-be-keras-tensors) but it simply does not work. All I'm trying to do is to multiply a tensor by a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the similar problem. I think out a solution, but did not try it yet.

1. Using Convolution Layers for Sequential model A which takes both Input2 and Input3 as the input. In this way, same convolution kernel will be applied to Input2 an Input3, aka the same weight W1.
2. Taking Input1 as the input of another Sequential model B.
3. Using a Merge Layer to merge the output out of A and B.
   And dot can be also done via custom function of a merge layer.

Comment: I am currently trying this (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297359/typeerror-output-tensors-to-a-model-must-be-keras-tensors)) but it's not working as I get a `TypeError` that says the output tensor has to be a Keras tensor.